# How can multiple pods have separate volumes mapping to the same Azure disk?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Currently we are using the Azure disk provisioner. As far as I can tell, each new pod must be given a brand new Azure disk to mount its volume to. This means that the number of pods (needing persistence) we can have running in K8 is effectively limited to the number of disks a VM is allowed multiplied by the number of VMs.

I can't believe this is correct - surely there is a way to abstract over the Azure disks so that we can have multiple pods use the same disk for persistence. And without using an overhead like Ceph?

Comment: multiple pods meaning multiple replicas or multiple applications (with multiple replicas)?

Comment: @AmritBera - multiple apps. So we could have PostGres and an ElasticSearch both using the same underlying Azure disk.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes - looks like Azure Disk can be mounted only on one node. May be try with AzureFile? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks#scenarios

Answer (score 0):

What it appears you are looking for is something called `Azure Files`, instead of `Disks`. The main difference is exactly what you are describing to desire: `disks` mount to a single node, and hence are difficult to access by `pods` assigned a different node. On the contrary, `azurefiles` will work cross-node. For more information look at either:

- [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction)
- [known issues](https://github.com/andyzhangx/demo/blob/master/issues/azurefile-issues.md#4-azure-file-dynamic-provision-failed-due-to-cluster-name-length-issue)
- [recent question by myself on a specific instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393001/set-volume-permissions-in-multi-tenant-kubernetes-cluster/54395681?noredirect=1#comment95698011_54395681)

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Add disks to the VMSS
2. Leverage a privilleged daemonset to mount the disk on the host node.
3. Add a hostpath volume to the pods, the hostpath is the mount point of the Azure disk.

In general, Azure files are suggested for your use case. But if you want higher write performance. You can mount the disk to nodes in this way, since only Azure Disk support write-back cache.