# Set Volume Permissions in Multi-Tenant Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub, kubernetes-pvc

Situation:
- users A, B, C, D
- team 1: user A, user B
- team 2: user C, user D

Desired:
- each user has private volume
- each team has a shared volume --> users in team can see shared volume
- some users, based on permission, can see *both* shared volumes

Searched for quite some time now, do not see a solution in the Docs.

Ideas:
- Use Namespaces! problem --> can no longer see shared volume of other Namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how you would do it. You can use namespaces for the different teams.

Then you can use a [`Role`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#default-roles-and-role-bindings) for each volume and assign to users accordingly. (Roles are namespaced). A sample Role would be:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: team1
  name: volume-access
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["persistentvolume", "persistentvolumeclaims"]
  resourceNames: ["my-volume"]
  verbs: ["update", "get", "list", "patch", "watch"]
```

Then your binding would be something like:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pv-binding
  namespace: team1
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: volume-access
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: usera
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: userb
```

The above would be shared by user A and user B. You can create separate roles for the volume that is private.

Comment: thanks for the swift response. This looks very clean. Question: how does this take into account the specification to look into the volume of _another_ team, i.e. default team volume only accessible for team members, but whitelist members allowed. It is my understanding that once in a Namespace, users in other Namespaces cannot access these resources.

Comment: Only if you use a `Role`, but if you use a `ClusterRole` you can go across namespaces.

Comment: hi @Rico, posting this here since this appears to be an unresolved issue per this thread with the official Microsoft Kubernetes dev: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/525

basically: trying to create the cross-node persistent volume as described above, runs into some issues using Azure as the managed cluster cloud provider. When requesting the shared storage in the form of an `azurefile`, the `pvc` get stuck on 'Pending' indefinitely. Any idea on what might be the issue here? any thoughts would be welomed!

Comment: Yeah, it would take it up with Azure support, it's related to their API and how K8s Kubernetes interacts with it.

Comment: ok we got this resolved: apparently their is a bug in the current API, where if the resource name is >24 characters, the `pvc` is not allocated. The Azure def was very helpful in resolving this in the end.